SQL Case statement solution
I am working on a piece of code to calculate the amortization amount.
For the below input values, I cannot divide the amount by 0, although this set of values satisfies the first when condition and never gets into the second one. How to resolve the error?
month = 0
number_months = 1
amount = 299
transaction_date = current_date
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN cast(month AS INT) = 0
   THEN (
     CASE 
      WHEN cast(number_months AS INT) = 1
       THEN amount
      ELSE round(amount / v_number_days * (DATE_DIFF(last_day(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", cast(format_date('%Y%m', transaction_date) AS string))), PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", cast(format_date('%Y%m%d', transaction_date) AS string)), day) + 1), 2)
      END
     )
  WHEN cast(month AS INT) = cast(number_months AS INT) - 1
   THEN cast(month AS INT) <> 0 THEN(amount - (
      SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
      FROM (
       SELECT sum(round(amount / (v_number_days * (DATE_DIFF(LAST_DAY(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', transaction_date) AS STRING))), PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', transaction_date) AS STRING)), DAY) + 1)), 2)) AS AMOUNT
       FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, number_months - number_months)) AS m
       
       UNION ALL
       
       (
        SELECT SUM(ROUND(amount / v_number_days * (DATE_DIFF(LAST_DAY(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m', CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE_ADD(transaction_date, INTERVAL CAST(m AS INT64) MONTH)) AS STRING))), PARSE_DATE('%Y%m', CAST(FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE_ADD(transaction_date, INTERVAL CAST(m AS INT64) MONTH)) AS STRING)), DAY) + 1), 2)) AS AMOUNT
        FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, number_months - 2)) AS m
        )
       )
      ))
  ELSE round(amount / v_number_days * (DATE_DIFF(last_day(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", cast(format_date('%Y%m', date_add(transaction_date, interval cast(month AS int64) month)) AS string))), PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", cast(format_date('%Y%m', date_add(transaction_date, interval cast(month AS int64) month)) AS string)), day) + 1), 2)
  END AS amortization_amount
FROM TABLE;


DATE_DIFF, PARSE_DATE, DATE_ADD and FORMAT_DATE are not valid Oracle functions so it doesn't look like you are using Oracle and I've removed that tag (and the other irrelevant ones). If you feel like the question should be tagged Oracle then you can add it back in and explain why it is relevant in the question (because the code is not valid in Oracle and is not procedural SQL - PL/SQL).

Please update your question with 1) enough sample data to illustrate the possible use cases 2) the result you want to achieve, based on your sample data 3) the complete error message you’re getting

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

SELECT 
    Country,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Amount >= 1000 THEN Amount 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS TotalSales_1000_and_above,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Amount >= 500 AND Amount < 1000 THEN Amount 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS TotalSales_500_to_999,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Amount < 500 THEN Amount 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS TotalSales_below_500
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Country;

In this example:

The CASE statements categorize the Amount into three different ranges: amounts between 1000 and above, amounts between 500 and 999, and amounts below 500.
SUM(CASE ... END) calculates the sum of sales amounts falling into each category for each country.
GROUP BY Country groups the results by country.
ORDER BY Country orders the results by country name.

Adjust the ranges (>=, <) and labels (TotalSales_1000_and_above, etc.) according to your specific needs and data characteristics.
